# Unable to deploy on Netlify because of npm dependencies issue conflict. At Initializing step, it breaks

Tags: reactjs, deployment, frontend, netlify

8:21:35 PM: build-image version: 20e1f1f500e4cbad9ea8a99bd40807bef3093551 (focal)
8:21:35 PM: buildbot version: 00a030bf3c001e3c0d5d2d5931d77655af9653ed
8:21:35 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
8:21:35 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
8:21:35 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
8:21:35 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
8:21:35 PM: git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/mrkirthi-24/CoinWatch-crypto-tracker
8:21:35 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
8:21:37 PM: Starting to install dependencies
8:21:37 PM: Python version set to 3.8
8:21:37 PM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
8:21:38 PM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
8:21:38 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
8:21:38 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
8:21:40 PM: Installing Go version 1.19.12 (requested 1.19.x)
8:21:45 PM: go version go1.19.12 linux/amd64
8:21:45 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
8:21:46 PM: Downloading and installing node v16.13.0...
8:21:46 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.13.0/node-v16.13.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
8:21:46 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
8:21:47 PM: Checksums matched!
8:21:49 PM: Now using node v16.13.0 (npm v8.1.0)
8:21:49 PM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
8:21:49 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
8:21:49 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
8:21:49 PM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
8:21:49 PM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
8:21:49 PM: No npm workspaces detected
8:21:49 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
8:21:49 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
8:21:49 PM: Installing npm packages using npm version 8.1.0
8:21:54 PM: Failed during stage 'Install dependencies': dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR!
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! While resolving: crypto-screener@0.1.0
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR!   react@^17.0.2 from the root project
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR!
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! peer react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0 from react-html-parser@2.0.2
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-html-parser
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR!   react-html-parser@^2.0.2 from the root project
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR!
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR!
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
8:21:54 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-08-12T14_51_54_173Z-debug.log
8:21:54 PM: Error during npm install
8:21:54 PM: Build was terminated: dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:21:54 PM: Failing build: Failed to install dependencies

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "crypto-tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
    "firebase": "^9.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-alice-carousel": "^2.5.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```